# div in position fixed with image under div with main content

Tags: html, css, position, z-index, css-position

i need to create a div in position fixed where i will put the image under a div with the rest of the content

i have put in my CSS `header {
    margin-bottom: 310px;
}`  to create a blank below space where there is gonna be my img in the `div id="background"` in position fixed below.

So then i have created the following id:

```
#background {
position:fixed;
width:100%;
height:100%;
top:130px;
left:0;
z-index: 1;
overflow:scroll;
```

}

and

```
#content {
width:100%;
height:100%;
top:60px;
left:0;
z-index:2;
overflow:scroll;
```

}

The id background is supposed to be the div where my image is gonna be placed right in the blank space l  after the header, the id content is the div where i am gonna have my page content and it start from the top.

Here the page : http://fiddle.jshell.net/CGJmE/4/

The effect i want to achieve is exactly this : http://tommywebdesigner.com/Home%20Page.html
but using the div to gain more flexibility. My problem is that i cannot insert properly my div id background in the position fixed with the image.

I think it s something very simple at this stage, How would you do that?

Hope the explanation is clear

Answer (score 0):

You need to do that with background-position: fixed

I've shown you in this jsfiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/CGJmE/7/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why you put `overflow: scroll` on `#background`, it does nothing, really.
Same with the `overflow:scroll` on the `#content`. It is redundant.
In general I do not quite understand what your problem is: http://fiddle.jshell.net/CGJmE/6/
I added `<div id="background"><img/></div>` where you indicated.
This of course still lacks styling for the header and content. (I added `background-color` to `.container` so it doesn't look too ugly). 
I assume you have that somewhere else?

If you need more help, please elaborate in more detail what your problem is.

Comment: Yes i am very close, but the images has to be fit into the space above the menu bar and before the content. I have updated it again http://fiddle.jshell.net/CGJmE/9/ , it has to look like this http://tommywebdesigner.com/Vision%20General.html

Comment: The example site you linked works differently. The background image is bigger than the visible part, but it is fixed in order too see a different part when you scroll. If you want the picture to be the size of the box, what effect do you want to achieve?

Comment: exactly i fixed it in order to see a part, but i want to achieve that effect, the image has to be fit inside thatspace bewteen the menu bar and before the content where there is the title Vison General, now the image goes also in the top and and down. Maybe i need to open an other div inside the div id background? I repeat we are very close. The link i sent you is the result i want to achieve.

Comment: ah, I understand what you are talking about now :) but to be honest 1. Why? is there a reason you want the picture to be only inside the div? the rest of the picture will be behind other elements anyways, right? 2. I doubt this is possible with pure css. you could write a javascript that gets run upon scrolling and adjusts the img in the div. this is NOT done with overflow: scroll and position fixed tho

Comment: exactly! , beacuse i maybe need to put in the future a video there! so that's why i need the pic being inside the div. What Javascript i should use? Do you have in mind? Thanks a lot

Comment: Put the background div where it is supposed to in the website. When scrolling, put a negative margin or position absolute with a negative `top`value on the image depending how far down the current view is. This should not be that hard in jQuery. Put overflow:hidden on the `#background` div.

Comment: Thanks alro, do you mind to show me  here and update it again? http://fiddle.jshell.net/CGJmE/9/ . so appreciate